# How can I change an http post value in controller before db.SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an input field that passes a string variable to my controller. I would like to add a timestamp to the field every time someone updates it. I'm thinking I need to change the post variable once it reaches the controller, but I don't know how I would go about that.

I can't really find anything that points me in the right direction. Here's my code:

```
    // POST: kursister/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "kursist_id,fornavn,note")] kursister kursister)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.kursister.Add(kursister);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../kursus_kursist/Create/" + kursister.kursist_id);
        }
```

I would like to alter the "note" before it is committed to the database. How would that be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            kursister.note = kursister.note + DateTime.Now().ToString();
            db.kursister.Add(kursister);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../kursus_kursist/Create/" + kursister.kursist_id);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @andreasnico. Marked as answer as it is shortest, simplest sollution.

Answer (score 3):

This really doesn't have anything to do with ASP.NET or MVC, you're just asking how to set a property on an object in C#.  You'd do it the same way you assign a value to any variable anywhere:

```
kursister.note = "whatever value you want to set";
```

> I would like to add a timestamp to the field

There are a variety of ways you might do that, but if you just want to appent a value to the property then you can do just that:

```
kursister.note = string.Format("{0} {1}", kursister.note, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

or a more recent syntax:

```
kursister.note = $"{kursister.note} {DateTime.UtcNow}";
```

Comment: I mentioned asp.net mvc as the variable that I need to have written to the database is passed from the view to the controller. +1 for valuable feedback. Thanks.